# Can I transfer images from the Phone to Windows?

Tags: windows, file-sharing

Almost every photo I take, I transfer to my Windows 10 PC.  I normally do this by connecting the USB cable between them and using Windows explorer.  All my phones fail with the USB connector becoming loose on the phone.  I normally charge it wirelessly, it's only the car Android Auto and Windows connection that requires a physical cable.

I would like to minimise the usage of the USB connector.

How can I connect the two using WiFi or Bluetooth, so that I can transfer files across.

Comment: If you use Google photos and set it up to sync you can [Access](https://photos.google.com/) them on the web and download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean FTP? You can transfer files from Android to Windows and vice-versa using Local area network. You can try installing [WiFi FTP Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.medhaapps.wififtpserver&hl=en&gl=US) and see if this is what you are looking for

Comment: Hi. I don't think OP meant FTP (although solutions based on it would be acceptable nonetheless). Could you mention the steps needed with WiFi FTP Server app so as to achieve the objective in question? Our site is a little bit different from the rest of the internet. We prefer to keep our answers detailed and to-the-point. Merely linking an app is not sufficient here.

Comment: I didnt, but its a really good solution as its more convenient to select the file on the PC than a small handheld device.  The only issue I have is that you cant change from internal storage to sdcard from Windows.  I will take that up with the author.

Comment: Once you have enhanced your answer, I will accept it.  You can add the 2nd, 3rd and 4th screenshot from their website

Answer (score 2):

[Nearby Share](https://www.android.com/better-together/nearby-share-app/) by Google, is available on Windows now. It allows you to send files or photos from your Android to your Windows. But it requires Bluetooth for the Windows.

To use it, you just need to install the application on your Windows by downloading it from the link I provide above.

Here's a picture of what Nearby Share on Windows looks like :
[image: Nearby Share for Windows]

And to send a files/photos from your Android, simply click the Share and click the Nearby Share button

Alternatively, you can also use [Shareit](https://www.ushareit.com/) or [Arc](https://quadren.github.io/arc/) which work the same but you have to install both app in your Android/iPhone and your Windows/Mac.

---

Conclusion :

If your laptop/PC has a Bluetooth connection, go with the **Nearby Share**. I really recommend this a lot, and it's made by Google too, and I've been using it ever since it has been released on Windows, where before it only work Android to Android.

If your laptop/PC does NOT have a Bluetooth connection, you can try using **Arc**.  It's easy to setup and the UI is user friendly too. It works both on Android, iPhone, Windows and Mac. It requires you to have both laptop/PC and your phone be on the same Wi-Fi/Network, doesn't matter if your laptop is connected through a LAN Cabble, it still works.

I use both of them bunch of times.

Thank you.

Comment: NearbyShare.  It looks like the apps on Android implement their own share list and for the two I tried, neither show NearbyShare.  But even if it did work and I asked for this, it would be less convenient than ftp.  But +1 anyway.

Comment: Found Nearby Share on Android, it was on an expected place.  But it kept failing.  I tried Arc, but usage is a mystery.  I couldn't see it on the phone.

Comment: Nearby Share on Android should be built in in your Android. Arc need to do some scanning QR Codes. Pretty straight forward on the application itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple webserver running on your computer using php and htlm.

Then connect to the server with your phone and upload all the files you need.

Comment: This could work, I already xampp running, so +1